# How to execute function from cdn script in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question. I have a script which i am adding like:

```
<script
  id="TestJS"
  src="https://test/uc.js"
  data-culture="EN"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
```

Script is referenced in index.html in my angular app. I would like to use function from that script , something like:

```
 if (getConsent('testParam'))
   {--do something with it--}
```

My problem is when i try to call it like that in typescript i am getting errors. Any idea how can i archive this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it like this:

```
 private giveConsentJS= window as any;
 public isConsentGiven: boolean;
```

and then in init:

```
this.isConsentGiven= this.giveConsentJS.getConsent('someParam');
```